# Defining functions w/ for loop & if statement to return array & sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm reading Eloquent JavaScipt 3rd edition to study JavaScript. I did one of the exercises in the book, and am sure it is correct. But obviously I am wrong because it gives me the different result than the solution in the book.

The goal is to

1. write a range function that takes two arguments, start and end, and returns an array containing all the numbers from start up to (and including) end.
2. write a sum function that takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of these numbers

Here's my code.

```
function range(a, b, c = a < b ? 1 : -1){
  let numbers = [];
  
  if (c > 0) {
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i += c) numbers.push(i);
  } else {
    for (let i = a; i >= a; i += c) numbers.push(i);
  }
  return numbers;
}

function sum(array){
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
    result += array[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Below is the solution from book

```
function range(start, end, step = start < end ? 1 : -1) {
  let array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function sum(array) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let value of array) {
    total += value;
  }
  return total;
}
```

So, if we run

```
console.log(range(1, 10));
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

my result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5]
NaN
```

The expected result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
55
```

To me, the codes look the same. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would first recommend that you name your arguments with names that better identify what they represent. There's a reason why the book uses names like "start", "end" and "step".

Comment: Typo: `i >= a` should be `i >= b`

Comment: `for (let i = a; i >= a; i += c) numbers.push(i);` probably should be `for (let i = a; i >= b; i += c) numbers.push(i);`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you. yes, naming arguments w/ names is better. I need to get eloquent w/ Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar Yes thank you!

Comment: @AndrewLohr Yes!! thank you too

Comment: Naming variables and arguments something that identifies what the data that they hold is isn't really "eloquent", it's just basics to writing clear code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: A contradictory opinion: https://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic

Comment: @ScottSauyet I don't disagree when we are talking about experienced coders, but with someone who is obviously new, using non-descript names is generally a recipe for confusion as is the case here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: I vacillate in my feelings about this in my own code, never mind for juniors.  But it's always an interesting point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop in `sum()` is wrong.  It should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
```

Notice how I am using `i < array.length`, not `i <= array.length`.

We want the loop to stop when we've gone though each element.  Using `<=` means the loop still runs when `i` is `10` and `array[10]` does not exist.